# UseSqlite with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core 2.1 not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am starting a Razor pages project in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I am trying to use SQLite but when configuring the database only SQL Server seems to be an option.

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Application.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Application
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Database.db"));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Intellisense does not recognize `options.UseSqlite` and builds fail. This was not/ is not an issue with .net core 2.0 projects.

Is this not supported yet? Reading through the documentation makes it seem that it is. I'm not sure what else is going wrong here.

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite?

Comment: I also tried with ASP.NET Core 2.1 framework error: NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.2 directly to project xyz.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It’s seems that you have not installed [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/) to the project.

Comment: Sometimes it's that easy. Didn't realize I didn't get  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite from NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

I also had same issue but after installing package 
*Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Version 2.1.1*

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite package from Nuget, and make sure that the package version is compatible to your target framework version as well.